# Safe PUT authentication in python requests

Tags: python, http, request, webdav, nextcloud

I am trying to make a script that uploads files to a nextcloud server via webdav. The documentation says this can be done using a PUT HTTP request, like so:

```py
import requests

url = "https://example.com/path/to/file.txt"
file = open("file/to/upload.txt")

response = requests.put(url, auth=(user, passwd), data=file)
```

This works just fine, and I get a `201` status code as a response, which means the file has been created, but I feel like its quite unsafe to do it this way.

I can add the parameter `verify=True` to make sure the file is sent encrypted if the web has a valid SSL certificate, but I don't know if the authentication credentials are encrypted too.

In case they're not, how would I securely make the request without revealing my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're PUTting to a url that starts with `https` so you're making the request over TLS which is secure if you have a good certificate. If you have a good certificate, your username and password will also be sent over TLS and be secure.

To find out if your certificate is good, try running `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443` from the commandline and check that it reports `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` or try opening a browser and type in `https://example.com` and see if the browser complains.